# How do I put async error handling into a separate function?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I'd like to put the error handling showed in the below example into a single function:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
import { tap, flatMap, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable()
export class ApiInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private auth: AuthService, private alertCon: AlertController) { }

    errorCodeToMessage = {
        500: "Internal server error has occurred. Please contact support.",
        404: "This resource can not be found. Please contact support.",
        403: "Access denied. Are you logged in?"
    };

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if(req.url != this.auth.LOGIN_URL && req.url != this.auth.REGISTRATION_URL)
            return this.auth.getToken()
            .pipe(
                concatMap((token: string) => {
                        req = req.clone({
                            setHeaders: {
                                'authorization': token
                            }
                        });
                    // Also handle errors globally
                    return next.handle(req).pipe(
                        tap(x => x, 
                            async (error) => {
                            const alert = await this.alertCon.create({
                                header: 'Error',
                                subHeader: null,
                                message: this.errorCodeToMessage[error.status],
                                buttons: ['OK']
                              });

                            await alert.present();
                        }
                        )
                    );
                }))
                ;
        else
            return next.handle(req).pipe(
                        tap(x => x, async (error) => {
                            console.log("the error is: ");
                            console.log(error);
                            const alert = await this.alertCon.create({
                                header: 'Error',
                                subHeader: null,
                                message: this.errorCodeToMessage[error.status],
                                buttons: ['OK']
                              });

                            await alert.present();
                        })
                    );
    }

}
```

However, when I do that, the injected AlertController no longer seems to be available.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
import { tap, flatMap, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable()
export class ApiInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private auth: AuthService, private alertCon: AlertController) { }

    errorCodeToMessage = {
        500: "Internal server error has occurred. Please contact support.",
        404: "This resource can not be found. Please contact support.",
        403: "Access denied. Are you logged in?"
    };


    async handleError(error) {
        console.log(error);
        const alert = await this.alertCon.create({
            header: 'Error',
            subHeader: null,
            message: this.errorCodeToMessage[error.status],
            buttons: ['OK']
          });

        await alert.present();
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if(req.url != this.auth.LOGIN_URL && req.url != this.auth.REGISTRATION_URL)
            return this.auth.getToken()
            .pipe(
                concatMap((token: string) => {
                        req = req.clone({
                            setHeaders: {
                                'authorization': token
                            }
                        });
                    // Also handle errors globally
                    return next.handle(req).pipe(
                        tap(x => x, this.handleError)
                    );
                }))
                ;
        else
            return next.handle(req).pipe(
                        tap(x => x, this.handleError)
                    );
    }

}
```

Runtime error:

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
    at TapSubscriber.<anonymous> (api.interceptor.ts:23)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:97)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:78)
    at tslib.es6.js:71
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:910)
    at Module.__awaiter (tslib.es6.js:67)
    at TapSubscriber.push../src/app/api/api.interceptor.ts.ApiInterceptor.handleError [as _tapError] (api.interceptor.ts:21)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:55)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1640)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:913)
    at Module.__awaiter (tslib.es6.js:67)
    at TapSubscriber.push../src/app/api/api.interceptor.ts.ApiInterceptor.handleError [as _tapError] (api.interceptor.ts:21)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:55)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1640)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with being outside of the closure, but I may be wrong. Why is that happening and what can I do to get a single function to do the error handling?

Answer (score 2):

If you make your errorHandler an arrow function, it should wrap the `this` context and give you access to the injected AlertController inside of the intercept method.

```
handleError = async (error: any) => {
    console.log(error);
    const alert = await this.alertCon.create({
        header: 'Error',
        subHeader: null,
        message: this.errorCodeToMessage[error.status],
        buttons: ['OK']
      });

    await alert.present();
}
```

Comment: Why is the function not having access to the "this" context in my example, tho? I'm trying to understand. It's an instance function, so it should have access to its instance and the other instance variables. Is the class getting instantiated for the second time somewhere without the variables being injected?

Answer (score 0):

Following changes in the code.

- immutable logic to update the request header. Use the same logic to
  update the params too.
- instead of tap operator use catchError operator.

```
intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (
      req.url !== this.auth.LOGIN_URL &&
      req.url !== this.auth.REGISTRATION_URL
    ) {
      return this.auth.getToken().pipe(
        concatMap((token: string) => {
          const updatedReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('authorization', token)
          });
          // Also handle errors globally
          return next.handle(updatedReq).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
        })
      );
    } else {
      return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }
  }

 handleError(err): Observable<any> {
    // error logs updation logics here.
    return throwError(err);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. That gives an error, tho, on the "return this.auth.getToken(),pipe(" line:

[ng] ERROR in src/app/api/api.interceptor.ts(40,7): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<void | HttpProgressEvent | HttpSentEv
ent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>
>'.
[ng]   Type 'void | HttpProgressEvent | HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>' is
not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<any>'.
[ng]     Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<any>'.
[ng] src/app/api